# Can I display an "incorrect password" message in a previous signin.html page after i have already moved to a logincheck.php page

Tags: php

my signin.html is just a common html page with username and password fields..nd a sign in button ..and i just want to display all those error messages under echo in the previous signin.html page.The code for logincheck.php is as followed:

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($username && $password)
{

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("project") or die("Couldn't find db");

$query= mysql_query("SELECT * From signup1 WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows!=0)
{
//code to login
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }
    if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
    {

        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        header('Location:mailbox.php');
    }
    else
     echo "Incorrect password!";

}
else
die("That user does't exist!");


}
else
die("Please enter  username and Password!");





if($_SESSION['username'])
echo "Welcome, " .$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a><br> ";
else
die ("You must be logged in!");


?>
```

Comment: **Please, stop using this code**. Your code is full of security problems. `mysql_` functions are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You're storing plaintext passwords and your SQL is injectable. That's bad.

Comment: I second both of these comments, though I've answered your question. You need to be hashing the passwords using at *least* `sha1` or some other one-way encryption tool

Comment: I too second all of the above.  The best password encryption tool for PHP is probably https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat which will become standard in PHP soon anyway (with not changes needed to your code).

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to make these both a single page. The form can point the same page and you can use a dozen variations to check of the POST data is available. If there's POST data, then process the login.

If the login successful, redirect if needed. Otherwise print the errors. Some sample code:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){

// logic to check login status

   if( login_successful ){
      // redirect user
      exit;
   }
   print "error";

}
?>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
  login form here
</form>
```

Comment: I've only down-voted a single answer on this question and immediately all of the other posts were down-voted. I'm suspecting it's all by @Allendar

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I misunderstand, but you basically just want to redirect to the login page, right?  If so, you can do:

```
header("Location: ./login.php?error=incorrect+password");
```

or similar, and then do processing in login.php to display an error message.

---

As an aside, look into separating your logic and presentation: [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [other PHP template engines](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20template%20engine)

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: could you please add a comment so that I know what the problem with this answer is?